# Relational design scenario: restrict children relations

Tags: database-design, model, entity-relationship, relational, relational-model

please consider the following scenario. An pet owner may have multiple cats, and may also have multiple dogs. Some of the dogs are related (ie they fight :-) ) with some of the cats **of the same owner**.

The following relational design does not impose this restriction, as Cats and Dogs of different owners may be related. Is there a way to impose this restriction by relational design?

[image]

Comment: Just add the OwnerId in the relation table between Cat table and Dog table.

Comment: @WahidBitar That alone is not enough - you have to ensure that the junction table matches the **same** owner as the cat and the dog, not just any owner. To do that, owner's PK essentially needs to be propagated down the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use identifying relationships to migrate the owner's PK down both "sides" and to the "bottom" of the diamond-shaped dependency:

[image]

Since `CatDog.OwnerId` is just one field, it cannot identify multiple owners per row, and since it's a FK towards both kinds of animals, this one owner must match both cat's and dog's owner.

In other words, a cat can only relate to a dog from the same owner.

As you can see, cats and dogs are identified differently from what you probably expected. A cat is identified by its owner and differentiated from other cats of the same owner by its `CatNo`. Ditto for dogs.

---

If you need a "simpler" key, you can always just add a surrogate key, or alternatively, you could completely eliminate `CatNo` and `DogNo` by "abusing" UNIQUE constraint solely for the purpose of migrating the `OwnerId`:

[image]

*(The `U1` denotes the UNIQUE constraints.)*

Now you can identify animals more concisely, but there is a downside: the UNIQUE constraint is completely redundant from the perspective of enforcing uniqueness. It's a super-set of the PK and the PK is enforcing uniqueness on its own just fine. The only purpose of the UNIQUE constraint is to enable `CatDog.OwnerId` to reference the `Cat.OwnerId` (and `Dog.OwnerId`) - most DBMSes require the parent endpoint of a foreign key to be a key.

Some DBMSes ([Oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2797775200346956958)) will allow you to use only one index to enforce both PK and UNIQUE constraint, but most won't. Every additional index hurts the insert/update/delete performance.