# Relate Reply Table to Ticket Table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

Assume i have a ticket/question that can have zero or many replies.

I can relate 'reply' and 'ticket' tables in two ways.

*First method:*

```
Ticket(**ticket_id**, title, message) //ticket_id: PK
Reply(**reply_id**, reply_message, ticket_id) //reply_id: PK and ticket_id: FK
```

*Second Method:*

```
Ticket(**ticket_id**, title, message) //ticket_id: PK
Reply(**reply_id**, **ticket_id**, reply_message) //reply_id: PK and ticket_id: FK & PK
```

In my opinion, both of them are correct.

As i see it, the Reply in second method is considered Weak entity because reply is strongly tied to ticket. However, i prefer the first method because its easier to deal with at the programming level; in first method, we only have to handle one PK. **Do you agree? Why and Why Not?**.

*NOTE: ticket and reply are mock-up samples.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As i see it, the Reply in second method is considered Weak entity...

Correct.

> ...because reply is strongly tied to ticket.

Not sure what you mean by that. It is weak because it cannot be **identified** without attributes migrated from the parent.

> However, i prefer the first method because its easier to deal with at the programming level; in first method, we only have to handle one PK. Do you agree? Why and Why Not?.

Well, it depends ;)

The strong entity and non-identifying relationship (your "first method"):

- May be friendlier to client code, especially if you use ORM.
- Prevents the parent PK from propagating further down the table hierarchy<sup>1</sup>, which:

  - Will make child FKs leaner.
  - Will "cut" the ON UPDATE CASCADE and prevent it from propagating further down the table hierarchy.

The weak entity and identifying relationship (you "second method"):

- Results in a PK that is a good candidate for a [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) key.<sup>2</sup>
- Avoids additional index on FK<sup>3</sup>, since primary index covers both fields<sup>4</sup>. Every additional index costs space and performance (when modifying data).
- Propagates the parent PK down the table hierarchy<sup>1</sup>, which:

  - May allow you to avoid some JOINs.
  - May be necessary for correctly modeling certain kinds of [diamond-shaped dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12626987/533120).

All in all, neither solution is absolutely "better" - it's a matter of choosing the right balance.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Not (yet) relevant in your case, since you don't (yet) have any tables that reference `Reply`.*

*<sup>2</sup> Many (but not all) DBMSes allow clustering only on the PK. In your case, clustering on `{ticket_id, reply_id}` (note the order of fields) would store all replies connected to the same ticked physically close together, dramatically reducing I/O for certain kinds of queries.*

*<sup>3</sup> Which would otherwise be necessary for efficiently enforcing the referential integrity when deleting or modifying rows from `Ticket`.*

*<sup>4</sup> Assuming you change the order to `{ticket_id, reply_id}`.*